# tasksel: apt-get failed (100) when installing ubuntu-mate-desktop

Tags: server

I tried to install ubuntu-mate-desktop with this command:

```
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

It seems that xserver-xorg was installed successfully However, in next line, I got this error.

```
tasksel : apt-get failed(100)
```

What do I do to fix this error?

Environment:
Ubuntu 18.04
Wsl1

Comment: FYI:  be aware the *flavors* of Ubuntu come with 3 years of *supported* life, thus Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 is now EOL. Packages in common with Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME for 18.04) still receive security patches, but the MATE packages do not. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm support; or see https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966

Answer (score 1):

Tasksel is dangerous application. Please retry with plain APT

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

Note: `^` in the end of `ubuntu-mate-desktop` means special task package as in `tasksel`.